# How can I get IE10/IE8 to pass "alt-d" through to the webpage?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

My primary mode of operation at work involves using an ancient piece of browser-based software that provides keyboard shortcuts through `accessKey="D"`-style [attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accesskey) on [HTML form inputs](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0101/0101-ACCESSKEY-INPUT.html).

Of the few buttons for which accessKeys *are* actually provided, the "D" one provided for in this software (which yes, requires IE) is just about the highest-value in terms of time I save by using a keyboard shortcut instead of mousing.

As far as I know, the way one is supposed to use accessKeys on IE is with <kbd>alt</kbd>-"key". However, you may know that <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> is a shortcut for selecting the location bar.

So anyway, using IE8 on WinXP, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> is caught by the browser and the accessKey is never sent through to the webpage.

But by some miracle, when I got Win7 and IE9, the browser seemed smart enough to notice there was an accessKey assignment and pass the alt-d through to the webpage! (Either that, or something was actually breaking and this was a happy side-effect. I don't know.)

Unfortunately, I booted up today to see that IE10 had been installed, and to my dismay the accessKey <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> shortcut is back to being broken.

**How can I get <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to be interpreted as an `accessKey` on IE10?** (Bonus points for IE8).

Comment: complain to microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting IE10 to emulate IE9 (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the **Developer Tools** and select the appropriate **Browser Mode**):

[image: 1]

If emulating none of the versions listed there helps (also try various **Document Mode** combinations), you're most likely out of luck.

Comment: Nope, no dice...